# Python's map function on attributes

Tags: python, string, io, map-function

I am reading a file

```
with open('file.html', 'r') as lines:
    for _ in range(19):
        line = lines.readline()
    line = line.replace('textA', '')
    line = line.replace('textB', '')
    line = line.replace('textC', '')
    line = line.replace('textD', '')
```

In total I have 8 of lines with replace. I would like to have a more pythonic way to do this.

Is there a smart way to do this. Maybe with the use of `filter` and `map` somehow?

Comment: Is there a pattern to those replacements?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, there is not a pattern, and I'm testing it right now. Also a lot of special characters, but the regular expression seems like it might work with some tweeking.

Comment: And by special characters you mean non-ASCII? I suspect that you are dealing with Danish text, at which point you want to *decode* your text to `unicode` objects and use `re.UNICODE` regular expressions.

Comment: Fortunately not. This is some results from a webpage (in English). But thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace):

```
import re
from itertools import islice

pattern = re.compile(r'textA|textB|textC|textD')

with open('file.html', 'r') as lines:
    for line in islice(lines, 18, 19):
        line = pattern.sub('', line)
```

where I kept `pattern` deliberately verbose; presumably your real replacements don't all start with `text`; otherwise you could use `r'text[A-D]'` for the pattern instead.

I used [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to skip the first 18 lines and only process the 19th.

Comment: Why not just **'text[A-D]'** ?

Comment: @volcano: I cover that explicitly; I am presuming the *real* text is not as simple as that.

Comment: Indeed there is not a lot of patterns in the strings I want to delete, so thanks for thinking ahead for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your example I'd agree with regexps, but it could be done more simply:

```
deletions = ['textA', 'textB', 'textC', 'textD']

for s in deletions:
    line = line.replace(s, '')
```

Comment: but for multiple replacement patterns, `re.sub()` is faster. And if there is even a little bit of overlap in the replacement strings you can simplify from a plain set of alternatives with `|` to more complex replacement patterns.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, unless the line is short and the substitution is being done a small number of times, in which case the overhead of compiling an RE might outweigh it. But in that case you wouldn't care about performance anyway. An advantage here is the programmer doesn't have to know the deletions in advance; they could come from user input without RE escaping.

Comment: This is indeed a solution I should have thought of. I just learned about `map`'s and now I want to use them all the time, so I forget stuff like this. However, I will accept @MartijnPieters solutions since it is more general.

Comment: In a more pure functional language, this would be an occasion for reduce/fold rather than map. But Python eschews all those in favor of things like list comprehensions.